# COMBINE HYPERLINK AND LOOPING VBA

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have a workbook that contains about 30 worksheets.
I have to link text from one-sheets to other sheets
if I doing it manually it'll take to much time
so I want to use looping the hyperlink

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    
    
    
    i = 2
    
    Set sht = Sheets("sheet" & i)
    Range("D3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "sheet2!A1", TextToDisplay:=Range("D3").Value
End Sub
```

how I can adjust this line
where can I input my I VARIABLE

SubAddress:= _
"sheet2!A1

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "sheet2!A1", TextToDisplay:=Range("D" & i).Value
```

Comment: If you could clarify where the hyperlinks have to be created (e.g. in worksheet `"Sheet2"`) and where do they point to (e.g. to cell `D3` in all other worksheets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Create Hyperlinks to Worksheets

- In a specified worksheet (`wsh`, `wshName`) of a workbook (`wb`), the following will create a list of hyperlinks to all the other worksheet except the ones in `Exceptions`.
- The hyperlinks will be created in a specified column (`hColumn`) starting from a specified row (`FirstRow`).
- The hyperlinks will be pointing to the same cell (`sAddr`) in each worksheet (`ws`) and will display text from a specified cell (`ttDisplay`).
- If the specified cell (`ttDisplay`) is empty (`blank` or `""`), the hyperlink will not be created but a combination of a specified string (`IfNot`) and the worksheet name (`ws`) will be 'displayed' instead, e.g. `No Value (Sheet3)`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub createHyperlinks()

    Const wshName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 1
    Const hColumn As Variant = "A"
    Const sAddr As String = "A1"
    Const ttDisplay As String = "D3"
    Const IfNot As String = "No Value"
    Dim Exceptions As Variant
    Exceptions = Array(wshName) ' add more?
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim wsH As Worksheet: Set wsH = wb.Worksheets(wshName)
    
    Dim i As Long: i = FirstRow
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    'wsH.Columns(hColumn).Clear ' Maybe instead of the following 'Clear' line.
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        wsH.Cells(i, hColumn).Clear
        If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Exceptions, 0)) _
          And IsError(Application.Match(ws.Index, Exceptions, 0)) Then
            If ws.Range(ttDisplay).Value <> "" Then
                wsH.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=wsH.Cells(i, hColumn), _
                                   Address:="", _
                                   SubAddress:=ws.Name & "!" & sAddr, _
                                   TextToDisplay:=ws.Range(ttDisplay).Value
            Else
                wsH.Cells(i, hColumn) = IfNot & " (" & ws.Name & ")"
            End If
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
    Dim sht As Worksheet, i As Integer
    For i = 2 To 5
        Set sht = Sheets("Sheet" & i)
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=sht.Range("D3"), Address:="", SubAddress:=sht.Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=sht.Range("D3").Value
    Next i
End Sub
```